# Adding category title to WordPress theme file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my archives.php file in my custom WordPress theme, I have the following code:

```
<div class="page-title">
<?php
                if ( is_day() ) :
                    printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'sturd' ),     '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' );
                elseif ( is_month() ) :
                    printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'sturd' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'sturd' ) ) . '</span>' );
                elseif ( is_year() ) :
                    printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'sturd' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'sturd' ) ) . '</span>' );
                else :
                    _e( 'Archives', 'sturd' );
                endif;
            ?>
</div>
```

I want there to be another statement so that if this is a category page, it displays just the category title in the page title div, and not just the word Archives (as it does currently).

I hope this is posted in the correct section.

Thanks in advance.

Sam

Comment: In the future, you might prefer to post WP related questions at [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you get aquainted with the WP [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). I would usually suggest using a separate category.php template file for displaying categories, and using [single_cat_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title) for displaying the category name.

If you want to use the main archive.php template, you can add an [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) clause and then use [single_cat_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title) to get the name.